# Explanantion of setter and NotifyPropertyChange method in ItemViewModel.cs of Data bound windows phone app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

```
    private string _lineOne;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineTwo;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string LineTwo
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineTwo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineTwo)
            {
                _lineTwo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineTwo");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lineThree;
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string LineThree
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineThree;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineThree)
            {
                _lineThree = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineThree");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is a typical ItemViewModel.cs page from a databound app of VS windows phone .

I have two qs:

First , what is the function of "if" statements in the setter of all properties.
Second , please explain me the working of the NotifyPropertyChanged method (line by line) along with the event PropertyChanged .

Answer (score 0):

> I have two qs: First , what is the function of "if" statements in the
>   setter of all properties.

It makes sure, that `PropertyChanged` event is raised only when property value actually changes. When it's being set to the value it already have update is just skipped, because it doesn't change anything.

> Second , please explain me the working of the `NotifyPropertyChanged`
>   method (line by line) along with the event `PropertyChanged` .

That's standard way to raise an event. Check [Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx). It describes event and how to deal with them. A shortcut: `null` check is required to prevent `NullReferenceException`. To know why local variable is being used read this post by Eric Lippert: [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).

Comment: This means that if i have a app that doesn't require constant updates from web i can completely remove setters property and NotifyPropertyChanged without comprimising my app's functionality

Comment: No, you should not do that. Without `INotifyPropertyChanged` your UI won't update when you change values in ViewModel.